# In which comic did Parmanu defeat Nagraj's immortal uncle Nagpasha?

Tags: story-identification, raj-comics

I remember reading a multi-star comic in which the clash between Parmanu and Nagpasha (Nagraj's uncle, enemy) was shown. Parmanu couldn't kill Nagpasha even with nuclear blasts because Nagpasha has drunk nectar to achieve immortality, but Nagpasha could easily kill Parmanu.

There was this scene in which Nagpasha launched a magical venomous weapon at Parmanu which could only stop after killing Parmanu (the weapon was following Parmanu). Parmanu decreased his size (like Ant Man) and flied at bullet speed right through the stomach of Nagpasha and Nagpasha's weapon followed. He repeated it again and again. Although, Nagpasha couldn't be killed, he could feel the pain. So, he called off his weapon.

Can you please identify the comic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the scene of Multi-Star comic [VIDHWANS](http://www.rajcomics.com/index.php/11860/1002/bestsellers/bestsellers-all-time/VIDHWANS-11860-detail).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. If the link you provide is intended to provide support for your answer, then please make it a bit more specific, e.g. by linking to the particular comic you refer to. If the link is just intended to promote your website and isn't actually answering the question, then [please edit it out](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/product-support).

Comment: It actually answered the question (I verified by reading the comics), but it had added comics code and a spam-like signature. I cleaned it.